# Silverstripe 3: Using member variable in registration content

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to display the email address a user has just signed up with in the content that is displayed on the page after registration.

My site is set up so that a user must click the validation link in their confirmation email when creating their account. I notice that some member variables can be accessed to be used in the email content section in the CMS, however I have overridden this section and am using a custom email template. (I am still using variables in the email)

I want to be able to use these variables in the confirmation content that displays on the webpage e.g.

> "We have just sent an email to XXX ($Member.Email)"

Is there some way I can access these variables in the CMS to do this?

Comment: Can you please share your form PHP code?

Comment: $CurrentMember is the template variable name. You will need the member to be signed in to access these. There is a way to log a member in with code when you create the new member. Its $member->login() or something like that.

Comment: @GavinBruce yes I believe it is $member->logIn(), however, I don't want to log the user in yet. I am able to access the email address in the code before they are logged in and I am wanting to do the same in the confirmation text

Comment: @3dgoo I am using the default form that is built into silverstripe memberprofiles. I have extended the log in form but that is just for other functions that I am using that won't affect this task (customising error messages etc.) so the form code I am using is essentially what is in memberprofiles https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-memberprofiles/blob/master/src/Pages/MemberProfilePage.php

Comment: Okay cool. A simple solution is when you redirect to the thank you page, add email as a query string and grab it from there using $this->getRequest()->getVar(‘email’) on the thanyou page